# Detect browser (+version) and device in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to detect visitor's browser and device with javascript? Something Google Analytics does in their dashboard. I found some scripts in Stackoverflow for browser detection but it does not work very well - the version wasn't not correct and you couldn't know if Chrome was used on Mobile or Desktop so the information wasn't relevant and I couldn't find anything that would combine both experience - browser (possibly version) and device via javascript.

Comment: "Does not work very well" is not a very useful comment. Please show code and effort and what does not work for you.

Comment: @mplungjan I edited the comment although the code is not relevant - it was just browser detection and you couldn't tell if it's mobile or desktop. I googled quite intensively but didn't find anything useful with both browser version and device detection.

Comment: If you actually want it to be somewhat accurate across as many browsers as possible, your only realistic chance is to use a library which keeps and updates a database of known browser signatures. Rolling this yourself in this day and age is an unnecessary uphill battle.

Comment: good idea, any recommended library for this?